# how to use for each loop in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to create Jmeter script for Restful API which has two parameters. One is ID and other is CODE. I want to use four codes for a single ID. I have 180 different IDs and 3500 different codes for 1 hour load test.

Comment: Are you inserting these values through CSV dataset config?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sounds something like this.

```
for( each ID )
{
    for( each CODE )
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If above my requirement is correct, It can be acheived by using 2 CSV files one for ID and one for CODE.

Take a look at this for detailed example, how it can be implemented. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/

[image]